# AWS Elastic Beanstalk and Docker - EXPOSE requires at least one argument

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dockerfile

Ive been trying to deploy my docker image to AWS beanstalk for the past couple days and encountered this problem which I couldn't find a solution for. When I upload my Dockerrun.aws.json file to my environment (through the console), it throws this error

```
Failed to build Docker image aws_beanstalk/staging-app: Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.072kB Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 2: EXPOSE requires at least one argument. Check snapshot logs for details.
```

The weird thing is that in my Dockerfile my EXPOSE keyword includes port 80 as an argument.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

EXPOSE 80

ADD application.py /application.py
ADD requirements.txt /requirements.txt

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install sudo

RUN sudo apt-get -y install python3-pip

# INSTALLING GCC
# RUN sudo apt-get -y install gcc

# DEPENDENCY INSTALATION
RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python3 -m pip install -r ./requirements.txt

# SPACY ENGLISH MODEL DOWNLOAD
RUN python3 -m spacy download en

CMD ["python3", "./application.py"]
```

Dockerrun.aws.json:

```
 {
     "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
     "Image" : {
      "Name" : "guppythegod/racheal_entrance_gateway:latest",
       "Update" : "true"
     },
     "Ports" : {
       "ContainerPort" : "80"
     }
 }
```

Here's a link to my image on Docker hub:
https://hub.docker.com/r/guppythegod/racheal_entrance_gateway

All my permissions are working and the repository that holds my image is public. If anyone can help me out, it will be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

`Ports` should be an array, like this:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "guppythegod/racheal_entrance_gateway:latest",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "80"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This answer has saved our teams day.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the ENV Port number solved my issue, and one more tip do git commit the changes before you do deployment  `eb deploy`

DockerFile

```
FROM node:alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY package.json  ./

RUN npm install

COPY . /opt/app

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx

COPY --from=builder /opt/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

ENV PORT 80
EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```